# Microsoft Edge 400 error in textarea

Tags: microsoft-edge

When i write my website nonwww domain (domain.com) in Microsoft Edge i get an HTTP 400 error. The problem happend when i write this inside textarea "Search or enter new website". This is default in Edge and everybody writes in.

I dont understand what could be causing this problem? Every browser redirects normally.

Should i do some customization in htaccess file?

I found this solution but it seems not to work and i dont know if i am going in the right direction:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Edge
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com/? [NC,L]
```

Comment: Which version of Microsoft Edge are you testing? I work on the Edge team, and would be happy to file an issue on your behalf for the team to consider. Also, a domain that reproduces this issue would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Because of many reasons, partly as a legacy from a time when users are less internet-savy, most browsers will [automatically](https://superuser.com/questions/965229/why-does-google-chrome-automatically-add-www-prefix-for-some-websites-but-it-do) [adds](https://support.mozilla.org/zh-CN/questions/908268) `www.` (*or* `.com`) when:

1. You enter a domain *without* the protocol part (`http://`), and
2. The domain cannot be found.

It seems that Edge 11 doesn't do that.
If that is the case, your direction is correct.

But you must do it for and only for the virtual host that serve the non-www domain.
If your server does not know it should handle non-www domain, the request won't even reach your rewrites.

By the way, you may want to remove the Edge condition and simply redirect all browsers, to save them from guessing.